# Is it possible that my element is higher than a iframe but lower than one of the iframe's content?

Tags: html, css

I have a page with a full screen iframe in it, and I have several button on top of the iframe, the z-index of the iframe is 10, so I set my buttons' z-index to 20 to prevent it from being covered by the iframe. it works fine.

however, when the user click something in the iframe, there will be a popup window in the iframe which will be covered by my buttons...I tried to set the z-index of the popup window in Chrome devtools, but it doesn't work.......

Thanks.

Comment: A fiddle will be more helpful...

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Is the iframe-d page under you control?